# Representación numérica del día de la semana para comparar dato

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Help plis, a través de una base de datos obtengo una fecha X y necesito obtener el número del día de la semana que representa dicha fecha, y así poder comparar si esta fecha tiene información o no.

Tengo el siguiente código:

Fecha que traigo de la base

```
FECHA: {{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($index->fecha_atraso)) }} (12-06-2018)
```

Con php obtengo el día: Donde domingo es 0 y sábado es 6

```
$dia=date("w");
```

Pero aqui viene mi dilema, por que no se como saber o como determinar que el dia de la fecha corresponda a 4 que jueves y yo asi poder comparar con mi base que el día que tengo registrado sea igual al consultado.

Ayuda por favor.  Estoy trabajando con laravel y php

Comment: Como lo tienes guardado en la base de datos?

Comment: supongo que las fechas las guardas algo asi : 12-06-2018

Comment: Perdón, la fecha la guardo asi 2018-06-12 00:00:00

Comment: A ver si te entendi bien, quieres extraer el numero del dia de la semana, ¿cierto?, ya lo sabes hacer con date("w"), pero lo que no sabes hacer es que diga: si es Lunes, Martes, Miercoles o Jueves, etc?, osea, que te de el nombre del dia?

Comment: Necesito extraer el número que me de la fecha, es decir que si es 12-06-2018 me responda que es 3.  Pero igual me interesria saber como obtener el dia, tal como me lo mencionas José Melendez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas trabajando laravel y tienes el modelo bien definido, te devolvera un objeto carbon de las fechas, por lo que solo tendras que hacer `$index->fecha_atraso->dayOfWeek`.

Si por el contrario te devuleve un string, pon el mutator en tu modelo

```
/**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'fecha_atraso'
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Con esto puedes obtener el día de la semana que necesitas

```
$day=date('w', strtotime($index->fecha_atraso));
```

y asi puedes comparar con el dato que traes de tu bbdd.
Saludos

Answer (score -1):

```
 public function acta_examen($id)
   {
    $tesis=DB::table('tesis')->join('comision','tesis.id','=','comision.id')->where('tesis.id',$id)->get();
    //dd($tesis);
    foreach($tesis as $tes)
    {
        //para obtener campos necesario de la tupla de la base de datos, el dia, mes, año y la hora, usando carbon
        //paquete de laravel para trabajar con fechas.
        $fecha=Carbon::parse($tes->fecha_presentacion_tesis);
        $nombre_dia=$day=date('w', strtotime($fecha));
        $dia_fecha=$fecha->day;
        $mes_fecha=$fecha->month;
        $year_fecha=$fecha->year;
        $hora_presentacion_tesis=$fecha->format('H:i');
    }

    //dd($hora_presentacion_tesis);
    switch($nombre_dia)
    {
        case 1: $nombre_dia="Lunes";
        break;
        case 2: $nombre_dia="Martes";
        break;
        case 3: $nombre_dia="Miercoles";
        break;
        case 4: $nombre_dia="Jueves";
        break;
        case 5: $nombre_dia="Viernes";
        break;
        case 6: $nombre_dia="Sabado";
        break;
    }
    switch($mes_fecha)
    {
     case 1: $mes_fecha="Enero";
     break;
     case 2: $mes_fecha="Febrero";
     break;
     case 3: $mes_fecha="Marzo";
     break;
     case 4:$mes_fecha="Abril";
     break;
     case 5: $mes_Fecha="Mayo";
     break;
     case 6: $mes_fecha="Junio";
     break;
     case 7: $mes_fecha="Julio";
     break;
     case 8: $mes_fecha="Agosto";
     break;
     case 9: $mes_fecha="Septiembre";
     break;
     case 10:$mes_fecha="Octubre";
     break;
     case 11:$mes_fecha="Noviembre";
     break;
     case 12:$mes_fecha="Diciembre";
     break;
    }

    return view('tesis.acta_examen',compact('tesis','dia_fecha','nombre_dia','mes_fecha','year_fecha','hora_presentacion_tesis'));
   }
```

por si a alguien le sirve, muchas gracias a los comentarios anteriores :)!!!